# Color cells when exporting to Excel from datagridview vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview, colors, export

I have code that colors the cells in a datagridview based on criteria. This works as it should.

[image: Coloring routine inside application]

The code displayed below checks the values under the header "As (Arsen)", compares them to the defined limits defined for ULxAS and colors accordingly. The result is correct and as shown above.

```
 Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click

    'If Not IsNothing(DataGridView2.Rows("As (Arsen)")) Then

    'Kategorier i kolonner (vanlig)
    'As
    Dim UL1As As Double = 8
    Dim UL2As As Double = 20
    Dim UL3As As Double = 50
    Dim Ul4As As Double = 600
    Dim Ul5As As Double = 1000

    If Me.DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value Is DBNull.Value Then
        MessageBox.Show("Cellen er tom.")
    Else

        For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
            If Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value < UL1As Then
                Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Style.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue
            ElseIf Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value >= UL1As And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value < UL2As Then
                Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Style.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen
            ElseIf Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value >= UL2As And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value < UL3As Then
                Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            ElseIf Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value >= UL3As And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value < Ul4As Then
                Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Style.BackColor = Color.Orange
            ElseIf Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value >= Ul4As And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value < Ul5As Then
                Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Style.BackColor = Color.Red
            ElseIf Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value >= Ul5As Then
                Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Style.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
            End If
        Next
```

However, when I try to apply the same logic to the export routine, I cannot get it to work. I have managed to get an export where the coloring skips the first row but otherwise colors correctly. The only way I could get it to work was to hard code the column number.

```
Private Sub ExportToExcel()
    'Annen fungerende eksportrutine. Formaterer!
    ' Creating a Excel object.
    Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    Dim workbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
    Dim worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet = Nothing

    Try

        worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet

        worksheet.Name = "ExportedFromDataGrid"

        Dim cellRowIndex As Integer = 1
        Dim cellColumnIndex As Integer = 1

        'For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
        '    For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
        '            worksheet.Cells(1, k) = DataGridView1.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
        '            worksheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()
        '        Next
        '    Next
        'Next

        'gets header rows.
        For Each column In DataGridView2.Columns
            worksheet.Cells(1, column.Index + 1).Value = column.Name
        Next


        'gets all other rows
        Dim rowIndex = 2
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
            If Not row.IsNewRow Then
                For colIndex As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Columns.Count - 1
                    worksheet.Cells(rowIndex, colIndex + 1).Value = row.Cells(colIndex).Value.ToString
                Next
            End If
            rowIndex += 1
        Next


        'As
        Dim UL1As As Double = 8
        Dim UL2As As Double = 20
        Dim UL3As As Double = 50
        Dim Ul4As As Double = 600
        Dim Ul5As As Double = 1000

        Dim Ul1Cd As Double = 1.5
        Dim Ul2Cd As Double = 10
        Dim Ul3Cd As Double = 15
        Dim Ul4Cd As Double = 30
        Dim Ul5Cd As Double = 1000

        Dim Ul1Cr As Double = 50
        Dim Ul2Cr As Double = 200
        Dim Ul3Cr As Double = 500
        Dim Ul4Cr As Double = 2800
        Dim Ul5Cr As Double = 25000

        Dim Ul1Cu As Double = 100
        Dim Ul2Cu As Double = 200
        Dim Ul3Cu As Double = 1000
        Dim Ul4Cu As Double = 8500
        Dim Ul5Cu As Double = 25000

        Dim Ul1Hg As Double = 1
        Dim Ul2Hg As Double = 2
        Dim Ul3Hg As Double = 4
        Dim Ul4Hg As Double = 10
        Dim Ul5Hg As Double = 1000

        Dim Ul1Ni As Double = 60
        Dim Ul2Ni As Double = 135
        Dim Ul3Ni As Double = 200
        Dim Ul4Ni As Double = 1200
        Dim Ul5Ni As Double = 2500

        Dim Ul1Pb As Double = 60
        Dim Ul2Pb As Double = 100
        Dim Ul3Pb As Double = 300
        Dim Ul4Pb As Double = 700
        Dim Ul5Pb As Double = 2500

        Dim Ul1Zn As Double = 200
        Dim Ul2Zn As Double = 500
        Dim Ul3Zn As Double = 1000
        Dim Ul4Zn As Double = 5000
        Dim Ul5Zn As Double = 25000

        'Virker! Men forskyver fargene opp ett hakk.

        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To -1
                If DataGridView2.Columns(i).HeaderText = ("As (Arsen)") And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(i).Value < UL1As Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.Columns(i).HeaderText = ("As (Arsen)") And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(i).Value >= UL1As And worksheet.Rows(i).Cells(i).Value < UL2As Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.Columns(i).HeaderText = ("As (Arsen)") And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(i).Value >= UL2As And worksheet.Rows(i).Cells(i).Value < UL3As Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.Columns(i).HeaderText = ("As (Arsen)") And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(i).Value >= UL3As And worksheet.Rows(i).Cells(i).Value < Ul4As Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.Columns(i).HeaderText = ("As (Arsen)") And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(i).Value >= Ul4As And worksheet.Rows(i).Cells(i).Value < Ul5As Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.Columns(i).HeaderText = ("As (Arsen)") And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(i).Value >= Ul5As Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet)
                End If
                cellRowIndex += 1
            Next
            'cellColumnIndex = 1
            'cellRowIndex += 1
        Next

        'ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Cd (Kadmium)" Then

        'Cd


        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To -1
                If DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = ("Cd (Kadmium)") And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul1Cd Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = ("Cd (Kadmium)") And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul1Cd And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul2Cd Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = ("Cd (Kadmium)") And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul2Cd And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul3Cd Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = ("Cd (Kadmium)") And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul3Cd And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul4Cd Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = ("Cd (Kadmium)") And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul4Cd And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul5Cd Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Kadmium" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul5Cd Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet)
                End If
                cellRowIndex += 1
            Next
            'cellColumnIndex = 1
            'cellRowIndex += 1
        Next

        'ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Cr (Krom)" Then

        'Cr

        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To -1
                If DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Cr (Krom)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul1Cr Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Cr (Krom)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul1Cr And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul2Cr Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Cr (Krom)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul2Cr And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul3Cr Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Cr (Krom)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul3Cr And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul4Cr Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Cr (Krom)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul4Cr And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul5Cr Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Cr (Krom)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul5Cr Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet)
                End If
                cellRowIndex += 1
            Next
            'cellColumnIndex = 1
            'cellRowIndex += 1
        Next


        'ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Cu (Kopper)" Then

        'Cu


        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To -1
                If DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Cu (Kopper)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul1Cu Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Cu (Kopper)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul1Cu And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul2Cu Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Cu (Kopper)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul2Cu And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul3Cu Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Cu (Kopper)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul3Cu And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul4Cu Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Cu (Kopper)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul4Cu And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul5Cu Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Cu (Kopper)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul5Cu Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet)
                End If
                cellRowIndex += 1
            Next
            'cellColumnIndex = 1
            'cellRowIndex += 1
        Next

        'Hg

        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To -1
                If DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Hg (Kvikksølv)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul1Hg Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Hg (Kvikksølv)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul1Hg And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul2Hg Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Hg (Kvikksølv)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul2Hg And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul3Hg Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Hg (Kvikksølv)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul3Hg And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul4Hg Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Hg (Kvikksølv)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul4Hg And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul5Hg Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Hg (Kvikksølv)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul5Hg Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet)
                End If
                cellRowIndex += 1
            Next
            'cellColumnIndex = 1
            'cellRowIndex += 1
        Next

        'Ni

        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To -1
                If DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Ni (Nikkel)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul1Ni Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Ni (Nikkel)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul1Ni And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul2Ni Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Ni (Nikkel)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul2Ni And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul3Ni Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Ni (Nikkel)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul3Ni And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul4Ni Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Ni (Nikkel)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul4Ni And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul5Ni Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Ni (Nikkel)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul5Ni Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet)
                End If
                cellRowIndex += 1
            Next
            'cellColumnIndex = 1
            'cellRowIndex += 1
        Next

        'Pb

        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To -1
                If DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Pb (Bly)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul1Pb Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Pb (Bly)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul1Pb And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul2Pb Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Pb (Bly)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul2Pb And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul3Pb Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Pb (Bly)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul3Pb And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul4Pb Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Pb (Bly)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul4Pb And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul5Pb Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Pb (Bly)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul5Pb Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet)
                End If
                cellRowIndex += 1
            Next
            'cellColumnIndex = 1
            'cellRowIndex += 1
        Next

        'Zn
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To -1
                If DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Zn (Sink)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul1Zn Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Zn (Sink)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul1Zn And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul2Zn Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Zn (Sink)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul2Zn And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul3Zn Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Zn (Sink)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul3Zn And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul4Zn Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Zn (Sink)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul4Zn And Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value < Ul5Zn Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
                ElseIf DataGridView2.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Zn (Sink)" And DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value >= Ul5Zn Then
                    worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet)
                End If
                cellRowIndex += 1
            Next
            'cellColumnIndex = 1
            'cellRowIndex += 1
        Next

        'End If

        'Else
        'MessageBox.Show("Cellen er tom")
        'Exit Sub
        'End If
        'Getting the location And file name of the excel to save from user.
        Dim saveDialog As New SaveFileDialog()
        saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        saveDialog.FilterIndex = 1

        If saveDialog.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName)
            MessageBox.Show("Export Successful")
        End If
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        excel.Quit()
        workbook = Nothing
        excel = Nothing
    End Try

End Sub
```

I would like to be able to reference the column header name instead of having to reference the column number, as these may vary but the names are constant. Also, I would love it if all rows got colored correctly ...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what the color coding represents I left this portion for you to decide. It appears from the posted picture that the colors do not necessarily represent simple values as the same value is a different color depending on the column.

First to your comment

> *I have managed to get an export where the coloring skips the first row but otherwise colors correctly.*

Again this is a simple indexing problem.  The line below loops through the `DataGridView`s rows.

```
For i As Integer = 1 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
```

The variable `i` in this loop is used as an index into the `DataGridView` rows. It starts at zero (0) not 1. This will skip the first row in the `DataGridView`. Start a zero and it appears to work correctly.

Second I could not get the lines below to work properly. The “As (Arsen)” part seems to be getting ignored. I change the text to simply “Arsen” and it appears to work properly.

```
DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("As (Arsen)").Value
```

Changed the above line to:

```
DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Arsen").Value
```

With these changes the code appears to run as expected for the single column “Arsen”. 
Since it appears each column may have different colors for the same values, I am guessing I am missing something. The deep if-then-else statement looks overly complicated. The code below uses a Select/Switch statement instead. To help, a simple Sub is created that changes the colors for a given column. This way you could identify the column and make color changes as needed for that particular column. Hope this helps.

Changes to the original code (with some variable names changed) is marked in comments

```
Private Sub ExportToExcel()
  Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
  Dim workbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
  Dim worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet = Nothing
  excel.Visible = True
  Try
    worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet
    worksheet.Name = "ExportedFromDataGrid"
    Dim cellRowIndex As Integer = 1
    Dim cellColumnIndex As Integer = 1
    'gets header rows.
    For Each column In dgvElements.Columns
      worksheet.Cells(1, column.Index + 1).Value = column.Name
    Next
    'gets all other rows
    Dim rowIndex = 2
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvElements.Rows
      If Not row.IsNewRow Then
        For colIndex As Integer = 0 To dgvElements.Columns.Count - 1
          worksheet.Cells(rowIndex, colIndex + 1).Value = row.Cells(colIndex).Value.ToString
        Next
      End If
      rowIndex += 1
    Next

    ' Substituted code below that loops through each column with data
    ' then sets the color for each of those columns by calling the SetColColor method
    For index As Integer = 2 To dgvElements.Columns.Count - 1
      Dim colName = dgvElements.Columns(index).Name
      SetColColor(worksheet, colName, index + 1)
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("Closing excel: save if needed!")
    'workbook.SaveAs("YourFileName..",)
    workbook.Close()
    excel.Quit()
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel)
  Catch
    MessageBox.Show("Error")
  End Try
End Sub
```

Set Column Color Method. You may have to adjust this to your needs.

```
Private Sub SetColColor(worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet, colName As String, colIndex As Integer)

  Dim UL1As As Double = 8
  Dim UL2As As Double = 20
  Dim UL3As As Double = 50
  Dim Ul4As As Double = 600
  Dim Ul5As As Double = 1000

  Dim rIndex = 2
  Dim cIndex = colIndex

  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvElements.Rows
    Dim curValue = row.Cells(colName).Value
    Select Case curValue
      Case >= Ul5As
        worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet)
      Case >= Ul4As
        worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
      Case >= UL3As
        worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange)
      Case >= UL2As
        worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
      Case >= UL1As
        worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen)
      Case Else
        worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue)
    End Select
    rIndex += 1
  Next
End Sub
```

Update Edit to use different coloring values for each element

```
Private Sub SetColColor(worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet, colName As String, colIndex As Integer)
  Dim rIndex = 2
  Dim cIndex = colIndex
  Dim ULArray = GetElementColorsValues(colName)

  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvElements.Rows
    Dim curValue = row.Cells(colName).Value
    Select Case curValue
      Case >= ULArray(4)
        worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet)
      Case >= ULArray(3)
        worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
      Case >= ULArray(2)
        worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange)
      Case >= ULArray(1)
        worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
      Case >= ULArray(0)
        worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen)
      Case Else
        worksheet.Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue)
    End Select
    rIndex += 1
  Next
End Sub
```

Method to get the color values for each element

```
 Public Function GetElementColorsValues(elementName As String) As Integer()
  Dim ULArray(5) As Integer
  Select Case elementName
    Case "Arsenic"
      ULArray(0) = 8
      ULArray(1) = 20
      ULArray(2) = 50
      ULArray(3) = 600
      ULArray(4) = 1000
    Case "Cadmium"
      ULArray(0) = 1.5
      ULArray(1) = 10
      ULArray(2) = 15
      ULArray(3) = 30
      ULArray(4) = 1000
    Case "Chromium"
      ULArray(0) = 50
      ULArray(1) = 200
      ULArray(2) = 500
      ULArray(3) = 2800
      ULArray(4) = 25000
    Case "Copper"
      ULArray(0) = 100
      ULArray(1) = 200
      ULArray(2) = 1000
      ULArray(3) = 8500
      ULArray(4) = 25000
    Case "Mercury"
      ULArray(0) = 1
      ULArray(1) = 2
      ULArray(2) = 4
      ULArray(3) = 10
      ULArray(4) = 1000
    Case "Nickle"
      ULArray(0) = 60
      ULArray(1) = 135
      ULArray(2) = 200
      ULArray(3) = 1200
      ULArray(4) = 2500
    Case "Lead"
      ULArray(0) = 60
      ULArray(1) = 100
      ULArray(2) = 300
      ULArray(3) = 700
      ULArray(4) = 2500
    Case "Zinc"
      ULArray(0) = 200
      ULArray(1) = 500
      ULArray(2) = 1000
      ULArray(3) = 5000
      ULArray(4) = 25000
  End Select
  Return ULArray
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks again, JohnG. I forgot to mention that there are several elements with different limits. I didn't want to clutter the question with too much code, so I only included the first set of elements. Your code does color the output, but colors all columns according to one rule. I will include the other rules and headers in my code.

Comment: You are correct. I could easily see that the coloring was used for something that was not defined in your question. Therefore it did not make sense to continue without this information. Since each element's values may have a different color coding, I created the basic `SetColColor` method which you should be able to modify the code to accommodate this different coloring for each element. You may consider each element could be an `Element` Class and each element object would contain the coloring constraints.. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks again, JohnG. Just one last question: where do I specify the column name in the SetColColor method? I tried several variations, none of which worked.

Comment: Assuming you want to loop through each element column, the code above simply loops through all the columns starting at column 2.`For index As Integer = 2 To dgvElements.Columns.Count` here I get the columns name and pass that name to the`SetColColor` method. In this method you can take a look at the column name (`colName`) and apply the appropriate coloring logic for that element column. Again since you did not specify how this coloring should work I left it to simply color all the columns the same. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Pleas see the updated code for the `SetColColor` method to accommodate different values for each element.